# MVC 4 mobile styles stopped working after script update

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET MVC programming. I've been using default MVC 4 mobile application template for my experiments. At some point I've decided to update the scripts to their latest versions (from 1.1.1 to 1.2.0 in case of jquery-mobile). For some reason the styling of the page is now gone. I know that this has nothing to do with my changes since I'm pretty much made none, so it has to be solely due to update. I was wondering if someone could point out to me what should I look at in order to figure out this problem, because honestly, at the moment I'm completely lost and don't even have a clue where to start looking or how to "debug" these kinds of problems. There's just too many "magic strings" in this template for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery.Mobile 1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, just use lower jQuery version.

jQuery Mobile 1.2 dont work with jQuery 1.9.1 and above. They have locked 1.2 to use jQuery versions from 1.6.4 up to 1.8.2.

**Proof :**

Take a look at this jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/yWTG2/, change jQuery version in top left corner and see a difference. Don't forge to run it after change.

With version 1.9.1. you will get something like this:

```
First Page
Next
Second Page
Back
```

Comment: Hmm, is there a single site that contains all the info about which versions work with each other? There are quite a few scripts in this template. How to manage all of them in order to make sure they will work correctly? I'd suppose the best choice for me would be to just revert back to default template scripts.